# Does a continuous random variable have only its range an infinite set or both its range and domain an infinite set?

Tags: probability-theory, functions, random-variables

Does a continuous random variable have only an infinite set for its range or both its range and domain an infinite set?

Likewise, may a discrete random variable have a infinite set for its domain? I think discrete random variables have finite ranges.

Comment: If a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) has finitely many elements, then any random variable with that probability space as its domain can take at most finitely many values.

Comment: Did a random variable come first or does a probability space come first?

Comment: In order to define a random variable, you first need a probability space.